# Converting ASCII Table to FITS image

Tags: python, matlab, fits, pyfits

I am a beginner in this domain. I have a text file having three columns: X, Y, Intensity at (X, Y). They are basically arrays (1X10000) each written out in a text files via python. To plot the dataset in python, I can simply use trisurf to achieve this.
But for further processing, I need to create a fits image from it. 
How do I make FITS image (and NOT a simple FITS table) out of the this text file (through python or matlab will be preferable).

Comment: Nothing prevents you from calling the same function in Matlab : http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/trisurf.html

Comment: True. But I need to do further processing in data for which I need FITS image. Just a table of grid coordinates with some value at each point does not seem to help. Hence requirement for conversion.

Comment: I realized that question was not conveying the message properly. Edited it. Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. You want to plot your data and save the image to a file, right? Or simply reshape your data into an array, rescale, convert datatype and save?

Comment: I want to make FITS file out of the ascii table I have. I do not need to plot it in python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do this mostly with Astropy.  The details are a little vague, but you should be able to read the text file into an Astropy table like:

```
>>> from astropy.table import Table
>>> table = Table.read('/path/to/text/file.txt', format='ascii')
```

where the options you end up passing to `Table` might depend heavily on exactly how the table is formatted.

Then you need to convert the columns to a Numpy array.  Your problem statement is a bit vague, but if the coordinates in your table are just pixel coordinates you should be able to do something like:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> img = np.zeros((len(table), len(table))
>>> for x, y, intensity in table:
...     img[x, y] = intensity
```

(I have to wonder if Numpy has a slicker way of doing this but not that I know of.)

Then to save the image to a FITS file:

```
>>> from astropy.io import fits
>>> fits.writeto('filename.fits', img)
```

That's the very high level process.  The details depend a lot on your data.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is even easier as you do not need the convert to NumPy array stage.

1. open ASCII

```py
from astropy.table import Table
from astropy.io import fits
table = Table.read('filename.txt', format='ascii')
```

2. write to fits file:

```py
table.write('filename.fits', format='fits')
```

Comment: OP explicitly said _"... FITS image (and NOT a simple FITS table) ..."_ This solution does not create a FITS image.